# STS+Scala Plugin compatiblity / project build issue

Tags: java, scala, scala-ide, spring-tool-suite

Have a project in STS e3.8(Spring Batch application), recently added some scala logic and installed scala plugin(e3.8), and added Scala nature to the project. Now i'm facing the problem that sts doesn't build project automatically. I have to run mvn build all the time manually. Also compilation problems in java files are highlighted only when you open the file.
Anyone faced with the problem and knows the fix  ?

Thanks

Comment: Specifically, which version of ScalaIde did you install?  Also, do you have Groovy-Eclipse installed as well?

Comment: Also, take a look at your error log.  Anything relevant? Paste it here.